# Recognizing Date inside of a string type in a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am attempting to recognize dates contained inside strings inside of a pandas dataframe. Inside of the csv file, the dates appear as: `'7\23\2019'`. However, when I printed the actual information to see what was contained inside of the cell, the following appeared: `7, 23, 2019`.

My original code to see if I could retrieve the dates was:

```
df.select_dtypes(include=['object'])
for col in df.columns:
    print(df[col].str.findall(r'\d{1,2}\\\\d{1,2}\\\\d{2,4}')) #to cover all potential basis
```

This of course did not work, as the information was contained using commas and not backslashes. The output I expect was:

```
Name: Date
0 7/23/2019
1 7/24/2019
2 7/25/2019
3 7/26/2019
    ...
Z 12/31/2020
```

However, the information I received was this:

```
Name: Date
0      []
1      []
2      []
3      []
       ..
Z      []
```

I then used `print(df[col].str.findall(r'/d+')` to see if I could see any numbers and I got the following output:

```
 Name:        Date:        
    0      [7, 23, 2019]
    1      [7, 24, 2019]
    2      [7, 25, 2019]
    3      [7, 26, 2019]
                ..
    Z      [12, 31, 2020]

 Name:     Int Col
    0      [12345]
    1      [31234]
    2      [51231]
    3      [61234]
             ..
    Z      [43523]
```

So, I modified my code accordingly to account for this new format:

```
df.select_dtypes(include=['object'])
for col in df.columns:
    print(df[col].str.findall(r'\d{1,2}, d{1,2}, {2,4}')) #to cover all potential basis
```

This is what I received as output:

```
Name: Date:
0      []
1      []
2      []
       ..
Z      []
```

I was unable to catch any values. What could be causing this lack of recognition?

**Edit: How the initial Date Column Looked Inside the CSV File -**

```
------------------------------------
|This Date | That Date | Other Date|          
|--------- |------------------------
|7/23/2019 | 5/12/2009 | 4/21/2015 |
------------------------------------
|7/24/2019 | 5/13/2009 | 4/22/2015 |
------------------------------------
|7/25/2019 | 5/14/2009 | 4/23/2015 |
------------------------------------
|    .     |     .     |    .      |
------------------------------------
|    .     |     .     |    .      |
------------------------------------
|    .     |     .     |    .      |
------------------------------------
|12/31/2020| 12/31/2012| 12/31/2017|
------------------------------------
```

Comment: why are you using `str.findall` u can try `to_datetime` like `pd.to_datetime((df['Date'])`

Comment: can you post the initial Date column?

Comment: @AnuragDabas I will put how the initial Date Column looked.

Comment: @Epsi95 that is a very logical solution, but I have several different columns containing the word date, in different way. I have to locate the columns where strings have this format and format them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `concat()`+`to_datetime()`+`dropna()`+list comprehension:

```
output=pd.concat([pd.to_datetime(df[x],errors='coerce',format='%m/%d/%Y') for x in df.select_dtypes('O')],axis=1).dropna(axis=1,how='all')
```

**OR**

use `select_dtypes()`+`agg()`+`dropna()`:

```
output=df.select_dtypes('O').agg(pd.to_datetime,errors='coerce',format='%m/%d/%Y').dropna(axis=1,how='all')
```

Now If you print `output` you will get your result

Comment: Like my comment to @Epsi95 stated, I have multiple date columns with different header names. I need to identify this format.

Comment: @QuestionAskerandAnswerer updated answer...kindly have a look **:)**

Comment: I received the following: `TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.nattype.NaTType'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid`. Allow me to edit my OP.

Comment: @QuestionAskerandAnswerer ohh...that was a typo...fixed it...updated answer kindly have a look **:)**

Comment: @QuestionAskerandAnswerer added another possible method kindly have a look **:)**

Comment: I just want to inform you that I am now getting `NaT` in my date column using these solutions. This  actually helps me somewhat explain why I was attempting to find the `d\mm\yyyy` format, because I just wanted to find the date columns. Some of the object columns which contained integers are now formatted as dates. I believe I will open a new question to answer this question. Thank you for the help. I will open a new question.

Comment: @QuestionAskerandAnswerer those values that are not in format `mm\dd\yyyy` are converted into `NaT` and those that are of format  `mm\dd\yyyy`  are converted to datatime If you don't want to format those integers then Updated answer...kindly have a look **:)**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235544/discussion-between-question-asker-and-answerer-and-anurag-dabas).

Comment: This is a significant improvement. It has recognized all the date columns, with exception to the last date column. Unfortunately, the first date pops up, and then the rest of the dates are `NaT`. I know that this isn't true for this dataset, because I specifically dropped data which did not contain these dates.

Comment: @QuestionAskerandAnswerer that was maybe because those dates format are not in format `mm\dd\yyyy` so `pd.to_datetime()` converting them to `NaT` in your last column

Answer (score -1):

Replace:

```
r'\d{1,2}, d{1,2}, {2,4}'
```

with:

```
r'\d{1,2}, \d{1,2}, \d{2,4}'
```

All digits (`\d`) must be escaped.

Comment: This solution unfortunately does not work.

Comment: Please edit the question to solve what  OP is looking  for, else delete this answer, because it doesn't solve the  problem in its current state.